# SSL - Null Prefix Attacks Still Possible?

Tags: tls, x.509

At DEFCON 17 (2009) Moxie Marlinspike  [gave a talk](http://youtu.be/ibF36Yyeehw) were he was able to use a malformed certificate signing request to get SSL certs signed for domains he doesn't own. The gist of it was that for the common name put something like `www.bank.com\0.iownthisdomain.com` with `\0` being a null byte.

Is this attack still generally possible, of course you can probably find CAs that are still vulnerable but are the clients, particularly Microsoft's SSL stack?

Comment: Ok. So Windows, Outlook etc. is ok. But what about Mac OSX ? Linux?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Microsoft has issued the [MS09-056](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/MS09-056) update which patched this vulnerability in [CryptoAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_CryptoAPI) on almost all of their operating systems, that automatically fixes it for Internet Explorer, Chrome, Safari, and any other application that relies on the CryptoAPI. [Mozilla has issued an updated quickly after Marlinspike's demonstration](http://www.digitalsociety.org/2009/08/mozilla-patches-critical-firefox-flaw/) and [Opera has patched it in version 10.00](http://www.opera.com/security/advisory/934)